# How to test setup.py?

Tags: python, setup.py, nosetests

I have been collecting unit test coverage from my library but, since I have no test case for `setup.py`, this file always gives 0.

Does anyone ever test `setup.py` using `nosetests`? Here is my file structure:

```
setup.py
library/*.py
tests/test*.py
doc/source/*.rst
```

Here's my test command. I ran it in the same directory where setup.py locates:

```
nosetests --with-cov --with-doctest --doctest-extension=.rst
```

The coverage output is like this:

```
----------- coverage: platform win32, python 2.7.5-final-0 -----------
Name                                  Stmts   Miss  Cover
---------------------------------------------------------
library\__init__                         18      0   100%
setup                                    10     10     0%
....
tests\xxxxxxx                            8      2    75%
---------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                   253     39    85%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Because setup.py contributed 0 to my coverage, I would never reach 100% coverage.

Comment: Typically coverage would only be calculated for `library/`, not for `tests/`, `docs/` or `setup.py`. How are you running the tests? `python setup.py test`?

Comment: I wouldn't test setup.py at all. It usually is very declarative by nature, and if not, it's fiendishly complex to test as it would require yo to mock away a lot of side-effect laden calls. Instead, if you have to have more complex logic in there (e.g. version extraction from a documentation-file, as I've seen the other day), extract that from setup.py, and develop/test separately. Then import and use.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I have given my command

Comment: @deets, but setup.py gives 0 to my coverage result :(

Comment: Have you tried adding `--cov library /tests`? See e.g. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-cov

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I haven't tried but tried with --cov just now. It does remove setup.py from the coverage report. In this way, I am happy too as it wont drag down my coverage figure